# Using DENSE_RANK() to pull data into columns from rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking to use SQL (Oracle) to pull data from rows into columns by evaluating dates on the specific IDs. Here is how my data currently looks:

```
|    ID    |   Date   |   Price   |
-----------------------------------
|   1234   |10/1/2020 |  $12.96   |
|   1234   |10/1/2021 |  $11.32   |
|   1234   |10/1/2022 |  $10.01   |
|   5678   | 6/1/2020 |  $59.96   |
```

Desired Output:

```
|    ID    |Yr1 Price |Yr2 Price |Yr3 Price |
---------------------------------------------
|   1234   |  $12.96  |  $11.32  |  $10.01  |
|   5678   |  $59.96  |          |          |
```

I have tried a couple different ways with no success. I believe the DENSE_RANK() function may be what is best, but am given an error that it is a window function and not allowed there. So I hit a roadblock and unsure of how to proceed. My current SQL code is:

```
 select id, 
       (select price from price_tbl where DENSE_RANK() Over (partition by id) = 1) as yr_1,
       (select price from price_tbl where DENSE_RANK() Over (partition by id) = 2) as yr_2,
       (select price from price_tbl where DENSE_RANK() Over (partition by id) = 3) as yr_3
    from master_tbl
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id, 
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as yr_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then price end) as yr_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then price end) as yr_3
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from price_tbl p
     ) p
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The data might be pivoted without knowing the number of rows per `ID` value, e.g total needed column count, by using dynamical pivoting through creating a function containing conditional aggregation such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Prices RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_str       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( 'MAX(CASE WHEN rn = '||rn||' THEN Price END) AS "Price '||rn||'"' , ',' ) 
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY 1 )
    INTO v_str
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY 0) AS rn
             FROM master_tbl ); 

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT ID, '|| v_str ||'
     FROM (SELECT p.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "Date") AS rn
             FROM master_tbl m )
    GROUP BY id';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then call from SQL Developer's command line

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Prices;
PRINT rc
```